# size & complxity of lower triangular matrix in 1D array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

i have (n×n) lower triangular matrix so what is the complexity of it? It says that would be O(n^2).
then what if i use 1D array for showing this lower triangular matrix, then what is the complexity this time?O(n) or sth else?
Compare both complexities of each turn.
for action run on c++.
i need the array size each turn.

Comment: *"if i use 1D array for showing this lower triangular matrix, then what is the complexity this time?"* -- what is your `n` in this case? If you want to compare this space requirement with the earlier one, `n` better mean the same thing, i.e. one dimension of the triangular matrix. What is the size of your 1D array in terms of `n`?

Comment: yes , actually i think we should get (n) in term of array size ,so we could explain the complexity and size of each array

Comment: @mia.tt When you say O(n^2) and O(n), n doesn't refer to the same quantity. The second n is the same magnitude as the first n^2. It also makes no sense to ask what the complexity is of a matrix. Complexity refers to algorithms applied to a data type such as printing it being O(n^2) or multiplying it by a scalar being O(n^2).

Comment: @user904963 Big-O notation is also used to refer to space requirements. While "complexity" is an odd word to use for this, I think it's understandable for a beginner to use it.

Comment: @mia.tt *" i think we should get (n) in term of array size"* -- if `n` is the size of your array, then both cases use O(n) space, as each array is exactly as big as itself.

Comment: *"Compare both complexities of each turn."* -- what is a "turn" in this context?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Complexity usually refers to a specific algorithm. So let's be more precise and say

> What is the space complexity of working on a lower triangular matrix with no other auxiliary space?

A square matrix (N, N) has a space complexity of O(NxN). A triangular matrix (N, N) has the same complexity because N x (N + 1) / 2 = O(NxN).

This does not change when you unroll your matrix into a vector. It's still the same number of entries, just stored in a different pattern.

Of course things change when you change your algorithm. If, instead of computing the whole matrix at once, you only operate on a single row or column at a time, then yes, the space complexity will decrease to O(N)

Comment: The space complexity is usually in reference to an algorithm, so it makes little sense to say "A matrix has space complexity ..." "Computing the whole matric at once" and "operat[ing] on a single row or column" could be space O(n^2), O(n), or O(1) depending on what operation is going on and how it's implemented. You could probably say that the algorithm of storing a triangle matrix has O(n^2) space.

Comment: @user904963 That's why I said "with no other auxiliary space", meaning any in-place algorithm. And if we are nit-picking, is storing a matrix an algorithm?

Comment: An algorithm that uses no auxiliary space has O(1) space needs. I know you said "other", but the input matrix is not *auxiliary* space.

Comment: @Homer512 *"is storing a matrix an algorithm?"* -- It involves a step-by-step procedure, so yes. For traditional matrices, the algorithm is on the trivial side, but it's still an algorithm. For space-efficient storage of sparse matrices, the algorithm is probably more complex.

Comment: @JaMiT So … according to what you said, storing is an active operation? I guess you define it as initializing or copying? I thought of it as the passive state of keeping it in memory. But whatever. While we are at it: Do you consider the output of an algorithm part of its space needs? Because if not, then "storing" a matrix would have constant space needs since no auxiliary space is required according to your comment. IMHO that's an utterly unhelpful definition.

Comment: @Homer512 Yes, "storing" can mean the act of putting something in storage as well as the state of keeping something in storage. In the context of "the algorithm of storing", the former makes sense while the latter does not. I tend to assume that people mean the version that makes sense.

Comment: @Homer512 Sometimes the terminology in ambiguous. The space required for an algorithm's input and output is part of the algorithm's space needs, but not part of its *auxiliary* space needs. Putting a (non-sparse) square matrix into storage needs O(n^2) space total, but the *auxiliary* space need is only O(1). Whether or not one or both of these measurements is helpful depends on the context. When comparing different algorithms for the same task, the space required by the task does not change, so it is unhelpful for "space need" to mean "total space need" instead of "auxiliary space need".